# How to remove tag content

Tags: php

I have change `$content` and i save in this change html code another site.
For example:

```
$content = "
    <html>
       <head>
           <title>test</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <div class='param1'>Some text 1 <p>:)</p></div>
           <div class='param2'>Some text 2</div>
       </body>
    </html>
";
```

How i can to destroy tag  with all content this div?

Thank you.

Comment: once please paste your required output. In case if you wants to remove html tags then use strip_tags(). http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_strip_tags

Comment: @DeepKakkar i dont need destroy all html code, i need destroy exactly <div class='param1'> with all content

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  But it sounds like you're looking for a DOM parser.

Comment: David, yep, ur right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
$content = "
    <html>
       <head>
           <title>test</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           <div class='param1'>Some text 1 <p>:)</p></div>
           <div class='param2'>Some text 2</div>
       </body>
    </html>
";

$pattern = "/<div class='param1'>.*<\/div>/";
$content = preg_replace($pattern, '', $content);

header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo $content;
```

**Outputs**

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>test</title>
   </head>
   <body>

       <div class='param2'>Some text 2</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually I was misunderstood with the question :)